# SSL keystore path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl

In my user home directory there is a `.keystore` file. Whenever I do `keytool -list` I get:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

However while running junit tests from Eclipse, the JVM is always referring to this keystore. How can I change this path to another keystore path, for example, `C:\Users\abc123\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\security\cacerts` from Eclipse.

I have tried

```
Debug As --> Debug Configuration --> Junit --> VM arguments

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/Users/b91255/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/security/cacerts "
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"
```

I am getting a certification chaining error. How can I ask eclipse to use `C:\Users\abc123\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\security\cacerts` as the SSL keystore?

Comment: Obviously not the best answer, but have you considered removing the empty keystore from your user home?

Comment: @ Aaron : I tried after removing the empty keystore, still getting the same error

Comment: After reading your question again I suppose it could be a problem with your junit configuration, which certainly will not take into account your debug configuration. I don't know junit that well so I can't tell you where to look, but I suppose a file search on your project for `.keystore` might do the trick. Also, having a certification chaining error doesn't automatically mean that you're not using the correct truststore

Answer (score 18):

in addition to @Tushar Patels answer, this is like

go to eclipse.ini file and edit:

```
-vmargs
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/Users/b91255/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/security/cacerts "
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"
```

Comment: I had an interesting scenario where I had added a corporate cert to the keystore, but it (apparently?) wasn't picking up the correct keystore. Once I specified the `-vm` option, it cleared it up. It seems like it's just best to either use this or explicitly specify the trustStore so you can ensure Eclipse is using what you _think_ it's using.

Answer (score 3):

You can set this in eclipse.ini file which will be in the root of the eclipse folder.