# PKIX path building failed - GRADLE (unable to find valid certification path to requested target)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, ssl-certificate

1. 1st I was getting the below error while importing a gradle(springboot) project into eclipse,Unable to download the dependencies from https://repo.spring.io

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

2. Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) and followed the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

- Downloaded the certificate for https://repo.spring.io in .cer format.
- Then imported the .cer file into JVM(means to **cacerts**).

Inside

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261\security\cacerts
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

too using the below command-

```
keytool -import -alias example -keystore  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\security\cacerts" -file example.cer
```

**But still the same issue persist**

3. Then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130840/ssl-keystore-path-in-eclipse) and added the below lines in **eclipse.ini** file to point to the desired path.

```
    -vmargs
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"
```

And now while running gradle build(to get the dependencies) I am getting below error

> org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: "C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\lib\security\cacerts" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Can anyone please help with this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You misspelled `Program Files` without the space. However, changing files under `Program Files [(x86)]` may not work in recent Windows (since 8 at least) because it is what most viruses and malware does.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, I did like this but got "Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\lib\security\cacerts" , then removed the space. AND I did the changes for both "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)".

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have copied the java folder to a new folder(C:\java\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\lib\security\cacerts , WITHOUT SPACE) and set the Environment Variables accordingly but still I am getting the same error. "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".

Comment: I hadn't noticed, but eclipse.ini although semantically equivalent to the commandline is not actually the commandline, and https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini says "using quotation marks around paths that contain spaces does not seem to work". Possibly using quotation marks does not work at all. Since you now have a path with no space, try that path without the quotation marks. I don't know what you mean by Environment Variables -- nothing here involves any environment variables, nor the Windows control-panel that sets them. -Dxx=yy is a system property, not an envvar.